# Substitute string in whole code below - Rstudio

Tags: r, substitution

I have a code:

`Rstudio Code:`

```
tt0 <- mean(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 0, 23])
tt1 <- mean(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 1, 23])
rt1 <- mean(na.omit(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 1, 15]))
rt0 <- mean(na.omit(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 0, 15]))
rt1 <- mean(na.omit(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 1, 15]))
mt1 <- mean(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 1, 21])
mt0 <- mean(tab[tab$Treatment == 1 & tab$Event == 0, 21])
```

Now, let's say that I want to substitute a string `"tabrob"` in place of everywhere you see `"tab"` in the code, how can I do that?

Comment: Scroll to 18. Multi-cursor support: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/rstudio-tips-tricks-shortcuts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RStudio go to search tab. give in: `tab` to find and `tabrob` to replace then click `All`
[image]